# R facet_wrap and geom_density with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

Here's my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(state = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
                 X1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 X2 = rnorm(100, 1, 2),
                 X3 = rnorm(100, 2, 3))
```

What I would like to do is to plot for each variable `X1, X2, X3` two densities/histograms (given the value of `state`) on the same plot BUT in such a way that all of the plots are on the same facet. I've done these things separately:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data = df, aes(x = X1, group = state, fill = state), alpha = 0.5, adjust = 2) + 
  xlab("X1") +
  ylab("Density")

ggplot(gather(df[df$state == 0, 2:4]), aes(value)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]
[image]

but I struggle to make it work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the three facets for variables X1, X2 and X3, each with two curves filled by state.

You'll need to convert `state` to a factor, to make it a categorical variable, using `dplyr::mutate()`. I would also use the newer `tidyr::pivot_longer()` instead of `gather`: this will generate columns `name` + `value` by default.

Your data but with a seed to make it reproducible and named `df1`:

```
set.seed(1001)
df1 <- data.frame(state = sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100),
                 X1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 X2 = rnorm(100, 1, 2),
                 X3 = rnorm(100, 2, 3))
```

The plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-state) %>% 
  mutate(state = as.factor(state)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill = state), alpha  = 0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to scale x axises individually for each of the facets? In case I have different distributions for each of the variables? EDIT: nevermind, `facet_wrap(~name, scales = 'free_x')` works perfectly.